# Action method in c#

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, action

I just want him to give me what has changed at the entrance. When I want to get the same value to the input of the select method, I want to get the same values in the action output, not the whole properties class WeatherForecast.

```
 public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}


 public void method(){
        Select(d=>
        {
            d.Summary = "dasd";
            d.TemperatureC = 25;
        });}

 private void Select(Action<WeatherForecast> func)
    {
        var result = new WeatherForecast();
     
        func(result);
        foreach (var item in result.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(item.Name);
        }
        var ss = func;
        
    }
```

'''

Comment: Please show a [minimum, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - how are you calling your Select method ?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the problem description.

Comment: i calling my select method in main method

Comment: Can I try and interpret? You're looking for a way to discover that `Summary` and `TemperatureC` are the things that have been changed, so you only do `RaisePropertyChanged` for those - is that right?

Comment: I just want to give the modified properties in the method

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a thing that you can do trivially, basically. There are three general approaches you could use here:

1. add change tracking to the `WeatherForecast` type, so *it* knows what has changed (usually with some kind of reset method to mark everything unchanged, and code in each setter to record individual properties as changed)
2. use an external change tracker which records the original state in a shapshot somehow, then later: compares that against the current value
3. if using an `Expression`-tree, interpret the *proposed* changes there - however: the C# compiler cannot interpret the code in the question as an `Expression`-tree (even though an `Expression`-tree of this can be generated)

Of these, IMO only the first is even remotely viable here unless you have a *lot* of spare time. Something like:

```cs
private int _dirtyFlags;
public void ResetAllChanges() => _dirtyFlags = 0;

private DateTime _date;
public DateTime Date
{
    get => _date;
    set
    {
        if (_date != value) _dirtyFlags |= 1 << 0;
        _date = value;
    }
}

// this name is a convention used by some tools; but this
// could also be IsDateChanged, for example
public bool ShouldSerializeDate() => (_dirtyFlags & (1 << 0)) != 0;


private int _temperatureC;
public int TemperatureC
{
    get => _temperatureC;
    set
    {
        if (_temperatureC != value) _dirtyFlags |= 1 << 1;
        _temperatureC = value;
    }
}
public bool ShouldSerializeTemperatureC() => (_dirtyFlags & (1 << 1)) != 0;
```

etc; this is clearly quite a lot of work, and doesn't generalize much.